# How do I pass a prop to a react component yet not update that prop in the child when parent changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [thing, setThing] = useState('a string');

   // code to update thing

   return <Child thing={thing} />
}

const Child = props => {
   return <div>I want {props.thing} to be initial value without updating</div>
}
```

If I want 'thing' to be passed from parent to child but not update when parent changes it, how do I accomplish this?

I've tried useEffect, tried cloning 'thing' to a constant within Child...

Comment: define a `const MY_THING = 'a thing'`, use that constant as the initial value passed to `useState`, then render `<Child thing={MY_THING} />`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `useEffect` with the empty `[]` for dependencies, so that it only runs once.

From [Reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array (`[]`) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on *any* values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run.

```js
const Child = props => {
  let thing = props.thing;
  let [initialValue, setInitialValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setInitialValue(thing);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      I want <strong>{initialValue}</strong> to be initial value without
      updating
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-williams-l6cgy?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try setting the thing to a variable in the child component when it's null. So when the parent update, you don't have to update the child.

```
let childThing = null;
const Child = props => {
   if(childThing === null)
       childThing = props.thing
   return <div>I want {childThing} to be initial value without updating</div>
}
```